# How do I install utorrent by hand?

Tags: installation, command-line, bash, archive

So I'm new to Ubuntu, in fact I've only installed it yesterday. There are a few programs I want to install.. both of which are a .tar.gz and a .tar.bz2 file. When I double click on them, they just open in the archive manager...How do I install them?

EDIT: The programs I want to install are Katawa Shoujo and uTorrent.

http://www.katawa-shoujo.com/download.php
http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/complete?os=linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]Open terminal window, than type the following steps:

```
cd Downloads

wget http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz
```

Next, run the commands below to extract uTorrent files to the /opt directory.

```
sudo tar xvzf utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz -C /opt/
```

Then run the commands below to change the permission on uTorrent-server folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

Next, run the commands below to link uTorrent server to the /user/local/bin directory.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/local/bin/utserver
```

Finally, run the commands below to start uTorrent.

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

If you get an error about libssl.so package missing, run the command below to install it, by APT, then try starting it again.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
```

Now that uTorrent server is started, open your web browser (Firefox) and type the address below.

```
http://localhost:8080/gui/
```

The username is admin and leave the password field empty.

The first thing you will want to do is specify the download folder. To do that, click ‘Settings’ button.

Then scroll down to ‘Directories’ and specify the download folder.

Done ....

Hope this help.

Comment: I'd recommend using /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin since the latter is managed by APT, so it's cleaner to install to the former.

Comment: The moment it asks for my password, the terminal stops accepting input. I feel like I'm doing something just horribly wrong.

Comment: Your password won't be echoed, but it is being accepted one character at at time.  Just type it blind.

Comment: right ... the password is no shown in terminal ...

Comment: Ryan, and so you already done the installation?

Comment: Ah hell. It tells me that "bash: /usr/bin/utserver: No such file or directory" after I just created it or whatever. When I tried to make it again, it told me it was already there. I'm lost. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does any of this have to do with me being 64-bit? Like, are any of the errors from it?

Comment: ok ... change the installation from /usr/bin/utserver to /usr/local/bin/utserver

Comment: only with this you will learn how to install this ...

Comment: no ... this tutorial will work in 32-bit or 64-bit

Comment: please see the screen shot of my terminal window, simulating the utserver installation in my desktop.

Comment: Well ... Good news Ryan ... it was a pleasure to help you ...

Comment: Is installing everything this complicated?

Comment: no, hopefully, you have the "Ubuntu Software Center", you can use to install almost the software you need to your desktop, and this we will named packaged software. However, some software only have the source installation, like you experienced with utserver, that don't exists in "Ubuntu Software Center" , and must be installed by source, or compiled by source.

Comment: The permission system is there for a reason, I do not think teaching people new to Linux to just 777 in doubt is a good idea. Actually I think it's wrong and dangerous.

Comment: In the future, consider using checkinstall for packages that come in tarballs (some-app.tar.gz).  It does all of the normal steps of building the application, but keeps track of what it does so it can uninstall the package later.  http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/

Answer (score 5):

> There are a few programs I want to install.. both of which are a .tar.gz and a .tar.bz2 file. When I double click on them, they just open in the archive manager...How do I install them?

In Ubuntu, you usually install packages from the Software Center. You can also install another package manager called Synaptic which gives you access to a much wider variety of programs.

`.tar.gz` or `.tar.bz2` "programs" are very often source code, which you must compile in order to get a usable program. I don't recommend you do this if you are new to Ubuntu.

---

Sometimes, generic Linux programs (i.e. not for Ubuntu, but *any* flavor of Linux) are also distributed as archives. For your examples, you can simply click on Extract in Archive Manager, and extract them to your home directory. To run them, go to your Home Folder, double-click on the Program Folder, and click on the program. For uTorrent, that's `utserver`; you should be able to tell which one it is for the other one (I didn't download it because it's a large file).

---

32-bit programs will NOT work on 64-bit Ubuntu by default. You need to do the following first:

- Open Terminal, with `Ctrl-Alt-T`
- Type `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs -y`
- Enter your password
- Wait for installation to complete, then type `exit` to quit the Terminal
- Now try running your programs.

Comment: I linked them .

Comment: See edit to answer, bottom portion :)  Please accept as answer if this helped you out.

Comment: Didn't work. And for some reason KS was like corrupt or something. It gave me an error.

Comment: Yes, KS errored out for me too. Are you running 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Yeah, the Vista already on my laptop was 64-bit so 64-bit Ubuntu seemed right.

Comment: That's the problem then. See 3rd edit to answer at bottom, you need to install 32-bit libraries.

Comment: I'm sorry...what?

Comment: For some reason, the terminal won't let me enter my password, it won't let me enter anything after I put in that command.

Answer (score 3):

Like explained before, some software is distributed in source code.

For this normally, you have to do:

- unpack the compressed file;
- Open a terminal window;
- Go to the folder you created when you uncompressed the file;
- chmod 755 configure;
- Run configure, `./configure`;
- Check for errors or dependencies;
- run `make`;
- Check for errors or dependencies;
- Run `make install`;
- If you don't have any doubts of dependencies problems you can run `make & make install`;
- If you have dependencies problems is better to run `make clean`, to clear the previous failed installation;

This method named compile software from source.

Comment: Whenever I type "./configure" into the terminal window it says that there is no such file or directory. Sorry if this is all basic stuff, I've only had Ubuntu for a day.

Comment: Can you put here the file list in your source code directory?

Comment: type in your terminal:
ls -la

Comment: Uhh....well..the file for uTorrent is called "utorrent-server-v3_0" and contains the files "docs" (a folder) "utserver" (looks like a program but doesn't open) and "webui.zip".

Comment: It told me that command wasn't found.

Comment: i will put one more answer with a tutorial for your installation problem, ok?

Comment: I appreciate it. Sorry if I don't get the basics.

Comment: i already post a new answer ... Follow the steps and let's put your utorrent server working ...

Comment: With software that's going to be available to all users on your system, you usually need to do a sudo make install for it to install correctly.